# Excel 2007 Macro move duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, merge, split, excel-2007

I have no clue about Excel Macros first up, so I really don't know what I'm doing on this, but any help would be hugely appreciated.

I have a spreadsheet with columns (no headers) in rows A - G.

Column A contains an ID and what I'm looking to do is cut any duplicate IDs from a column structure to a row structure.  There could be up to 9 rows that need moving per ID.

e.g.
Current format:

```
Row 1 - ID123 / Bob / James / 12345 / 1 / A1 / 120
Row 2 - ID124 / John / Smith / 2351 / 5 / C2 / 121
Row 3 - ID124 / John / Smith / 25562 / 1 / A2 / 162
Row 4 - ID162 / Gary / Barlow / 251767 / 9 / B1 / 167
```

Target format:

```
Row 1 - ID123 / Bob / James / 12345 / 1 / A1 / 120
Row 2 - ID124 / John / Smith / 2351 / 5 / C2 / 121 / 25562 / 1 / A2 / 162
Row 3 - ID162 / Gary / Barlow / 251767 / 9 / B1 / 167
```

So my question is - 
a) is this doable
b) how would I go about doing this (I'm happy to make the solution myself, but as I am a VBA beginner, being pointed in the right direction would be handy!)

How the data would look before the macro is applied

[image: Example data]

How the data should end up looking

[image: How that data should end up looking]

Comment: a) sure. b) without writing a whole solution right now I would start looping through rows, saving the IDs you find, then when you find a duplicate (something you already found), go back to that row, append the new values, and delete the later row

Comment: The poor man's solution would be just to do a pivot table though, you should be able to group data that way and get something close. Not sure if this is an option for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try. It is using a `dictionary` object. This solution assumes each row starts with `Row 1 - ID123 / Bob / James` pattern.

```
Option Explicit

Sub mergeDuplicates()
Dim d As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Set rng = Sheets(3).Range("A2:H5")
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
vArr = rng.Value

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    If Not d.Exists(vArr(i, 2)) Then '-- check for unique ID
        d.Add vArr(i, 2), Trim(Replace(vArr(i, 1), "-", ""))
        For j = 2 To UBound(vArr, 2)
            d.Item(vArr(i, 2)) = d.Item(vArr(i, 2)) + "/" & Trim(Replace(vArr(i, j), "/", ""))
        Next j
    Else
        For j = 5 To UBound(vArr, 2)
            d.Item(vArr(i, 2)) = d.Item(vArr(i, 2)) + "/" & Trim(Replace(vArr(i, j), "/", ""))
        Next j
    End If
Next i

'-- output to sheet
rng.Offset(5).Resize(UBound(d.items) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(d.items)

'-- split the text to columns
rng.Offset(5).Resize(UBound(d.items) + 1, 1).TextToColumns Destination:= _
        rng.Offset(5), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, OtherChar:="/"

Set d = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

### AS per OP's comments and updates

Changing the `for loop` contents to fit according to his real data.

```
For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    If Not d.Exists(vArr(i, 1)) Then '-- check for unique ID
        d.Add vArr(i, 1), Trim(vArr(i, 1)) '-- add RowID as first element in item
        For j = 2 To UBound(vArr, 2)  '-- then append each element(column) to the first element
            d.Item(vArr(i, 1)) = d.Item(vArr(i, 1)) + "/" & Trim(Replace(vArr(i, j), "/", ""))
        Next j
    Else
        For j = 4 To UBound(vArr, 2)  '-- when duplicates found, append from 4th column
            d.Item(vArr(i, 1)) = d.Item(vArr(i, 1)) + "/" & Trim(Replace(vArr(i, j), "/", ""))
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

**Output based on the OP's updated sample data:**

[image]

Comment: @sam.clements please give this a try if you are interested, then comment. Sheets, ranges are static in this solution as it's a demo. You may set them according to yours.

Comment: Hi BonCodigo, Having some issues getting this to work, but probably due to my setup!  There is no "Row 1 -" "Row 2 -" etc or the "/" in the data, I just put it in the question to try to show the format of my data!

Comment: To be specific - I've changed the  range to
Set rng = Sheets(3).Range("A2:G500")
to accommodate the lack of the first row (and to work over a bigger range)
and I'm getting a "Type Mismatch" on the line
rng.Offset(5).Resize(UBound(d.items) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(d.items)

Comment: @sam.clements can you **append** the exact correct few sample rows? (don't change earlier sample data please). Even better if you could show a clear screen shot of few sample rows.

Comment: Done - didn't realise you could add images, otherwise I would have done so!

Comment: @sam.clements take a look at the udpated code according to your correct sample data. Please mark up/vote up the answer if all good with you.

Comment: Hi, I changed the range to Set rng = Sheets(3).Range("A2:G500") to reflect the correct size of the data, but it's throwing up a type mismatch error on the Output to Sheet line.

Comment: I output to the same sheet for demo purpose. Why don't you output to a new Sheet, that will save your from the headache... rng.Offset(5) this to appropriate sheet name and range.

Comment: Sorry for the, no doubt, basic question, but if I want it to output to Sheet1, do I simply change all the references to rng.Offset(5) to rng.Sheet1? Sorry, very basic knowledge!

Comment: To make things easier for you, you can run entire code in Sheet(3) as you have set the range. Then output into Sheet(1) on the comments that says output and split into columns. `Sheets(1).Range("A1")..Resize...` and `Destination:= Sheets(1).Range("A1")`

Comment: :D Glad you got it worked. Let us know if you have further questions. BTW you can replace this like `vArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value))` with `vArr = rng.Value`. Both the same..

Comment: Hi, it worked absolutely fine for a couple of weeks worth of data, but on the most recent week of data it's throwing a mismatch error. None of the data types have changed, so I'm a little confused as to how to go about sorting this!  I changed the range and identified that it's throwing the error on a blank row (there are multiple blank rows however) and have tried deleting the row or changing the data type, but am still getting the error! Any ideas?

Comment: Can you send a sheet with sample data (not all data, then hard to download, and work..)? Make sure to send the file that has an error. I am not a big fan of looking into files frop OP. But in your case I guess, let me look at your sheet. There's my email on main page.